# Will apple approve an app for beta testing without app icons?

Tags: ios

I'm waiting for the design team to finish app icons, I'm wondering if I can save time and go ahead and post the first version of the app for Apple review so we can start beta testing it.

Clarification: I'm not talking about publishing my App to the store but send it for initial review to start beta testing.

**EDIT**

There is some controversy about Apple testing or not beta binaries but it seems they do it according this

> Your app must pass Beta App Review before you can invite your external testers to test it (see Submitting an App for Beta App Review). The build will be available to them for 30 days after the invitations are sent.

[TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)

Comment: the apps for beta testing aren't reviewed by apple

Comment: @jcesarmobile: but app takes about a day to be ready for beta testing, why's that?

Comment: Mine usually take only a few minutes

Comment: @jcesarmobile: I'm talking about the very first "major" version. It takes about a day for first time, then it takes minutes as you say

Comment: Even if the first version takes more time, they don't review it. The day you release the final version you'll see that the review process takes 7-10 days

Comment: You were not able to upload the application on apple store without app icon. During uploading the build using "App Loader" you will get the error message to add icons in the build.

Comment: @jcesarmobile: please see my edit. I believe they do test... unless they pretend to do it and retain App for a day for no reason :)

Comment: Ok, so, if you use internal testing it doesn't pass apple review, if you do external testing you have to pass an app review. You can't submit the app without images/icons, but you can use black or white placeholder images

Comment: @StackOverflower This is only if you want to allow external tester for testing.
AppStore Review and TestFlightBeta both are different things.

Comment: @V.J.: correct, but without AppStore Beta Review I can't beta test with external users so they are connected. Approved your answer since it's enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: Internal Beta testing via TestFlight does not require a review but is limited to 25 testers and they need to be added in iTunes Connect. External Beta testing via TestFlight does require a review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without app icon you are not able to upload the build. Application Loader will show you the error to add icons in the build.

The error message would be like below.

```
Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format
```

More information :

You can/could upload another version of your app on a private store, and since there are no guidelines/prerequisites there, you could upload without a fully finished app. **It would require an Entreprise account**, and wouldn't "save" you much time in the review process, but it's a different way to beta test your app.

The cycle we use where I work is : upload an entreprise version for the company to test, and then submit an appstore version. This way, you have 100% control over your entreprise versioning/beta testing, and so on.

Comment: Yep, i was about to write that. You need a fully complete binary with images, loading screen and all that good jazz to even be able to upload.

Comment: I'll be honest, I thought it was a good idea but I agree, it's a lot of more text for not that much more information. Feel free to submit an edit where you remove it, I don't really mind. I'd rather have too much than not enough, but on the other hand we lose readablity. I won't mind if you decide to remove it. :)